# Entity Framework Core and CosmosDb - issue when querying a property having the type enum and being serialized as string

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have configured an EF Core 3.1.2 model to serialize enums as strings instead of integers. Now the queries cannot be evaluated on the server. The code below demonstrates the issue. Is there a way to serialize enums as strings and still evaluate the queries on the server?

The code below demonstrates the issue.

```
// Referenced NuGet packages:
// - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2
// - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 3.1.2
// - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.1.2

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace CosmosDbDemo
{
  #region CosmosDb parameters
  // Define here your CosmosDb database connection
  class CosmosDbParameters
  {
    public const string AccountEndPoint = "{YOUR-ENDPOINT-HERE}";
    public const string AccountKey = "{YOUR-ACCOUNT-KEY-HERE}";
    public const string DbName = "DemoIssues";
    public const string DbContainer = "Offers";
  }
#endregion


class Program
{
    static async Task Main( string[] args )
    {
        // Configure services
        var serviceProvider =
            new ServiceCollection()
            .AddDbContext<OfferContext>( 
                options => options.UseCosmos(  CosmosDbParameters.AccountEndPoint, CosmosDbParameters.AccountKey, CosmosDbParameters.DbName ) )
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        using var ctx = serviceProvider.GetService<OfferContext>();

        // Ensure database has been properly created.
        ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Insert some items. A future query will try to retrieve only some of them.
        await AddItems( ctx );

        // Query for some items. Reproduces the issue with enums
        // serialized as text.
        await QueryUsingEFWithServerEvaluation( ctx );

        // Query for items, but first pull all items to the client
        // and then execute a filtering operation. This one works,
        // but it's not acceptable.
        await QueryUsingEFWithClientEvaluation( ctx );
    }

    private static async Task QueryUsingEFWithClientEvaluation( OfferContext ctx )
    {
        try
        {
            var offers = await ctx
                            .Offers
                            .ToListAsync();
            offers = offers.Where( _ => _.Status == OfferStatus.Created ).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine( $"With client evaluation: {offers.Count} offers found" );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.Write( ex );
        }
    }

    private static async Task QueryUsingEFWithServerEvaluation( OfferContext ctx )
    {
        try
        {
            // The call below fails with exception
            // "Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'CosmosDbDemo.Model.OfferStatus'"
            var offers = await ctx
                            .Offers
                            .Where( _ => _.Status == OfferStatus.Created  )
                            .ToListAsync();

            Console.WriteLine( $"With server evaluation: {offers.Count} offers found" );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.Write( ex );
        }
    }

    private static async Task AddItems( OfferContext ctx )
    {
        var offer = BuildOffer( "Acme Offer 1", 14 );
        ctx.Add( offer );
        offer = BuildOffer( "Acme Offer 2", 30 );
        ctx.Add( offer );
        offer = BuildOffer( "Coyote Ugly Super Offer 1", 25 );
        ctx.Add( offer );
        offer = BuildOffer( "Sloth Supercars Offer 14", 10 );
        ctx.Add( offer );
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private static Offer BuildOffer( string name, int valabilityInDays )
    {
        var result = new Offer
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = name,
            ExpirationDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays( valabilityInDays ),
            Status = OfferStatus.Created
        };

        return result;
    }
}

class Offer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDateUtc { get; set; }
    public OfferStatus Status { get; set; }
}

enum OfferStatus
{
    Created = 0,
    Approved = 1,
    Accepted = 2,
    Declined = 3
}

class OfferContext : DbContext
{
    public OfferContext( DbContextOptions<OfferContext> options ) : base( options )
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Offer> Offers { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultContainer( CosmosDbParameters.DbContainer );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>().HasPartitionKey( _ => _.Id );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>().Property( _ => _.Id )
                .HasConversion( _ => _.ToString( "B" ), _ => Guid.Parse( _ ) );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>().Property( _ => _.Status )
                .HasConversion( _ => _.ToString(), _ => (OfferStatus)Enum.Parse( typeof( OfferStatus ), _ ) );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: No, for now I am reading all items locally and then filtering them (I can do this as the total number of items is small, maybe 50). I can improve the situation by executing some filters on the server and only the enum-based ones locally, but I didn't get there yet.